# What should I do if a user is constantly putting the post in reopen review?

Tags: support, review-queues, closed-questions, abuse, trivial

I was one of the users who closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69496547/15781079). If you look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69496547/revisions) you will see the user keeps editing the question without effort and putting it into reopen review queue. The edits are small and do not provide debugging details (close reason). Instead they simply re-word it (I played a new song -> bot is used again). I ended up leaving a comment and flagging for moderator attention. Was this the right action or should I have done something different?

Comment: Heh, that's interesting. I wonder if the system could let this go like that dozens of times.?

Comment: My understanding of the Reopen Queue changes is that users now had multiple chances at reopening but not infinite changes. I think if this user is able to attempt again it might be a bug. EDIT: Nope, I'm an idiot. There is no limit on the number of attempts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release

Comment: You might want to leave an answer on that post about what you're seeing since they said they want to see if any abuse of the feature is happening.

Comment: Surprise surprise, the decision to make the checkbox to push a question into the reopen queue usable multiple times leaves it open to abuse :facepalm:

Comment: It was raised at least a few times on the original MSE post that some mechanism for recognizing repeated ***failed*** attempts of a *"substantial edit"* should cause an automatic "ban" for substantial edits. I'm guessing it didn't happen...

Comment: Related (mostly historical, my emphasis): *[Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947)* (`status-completed`) - *"We have disabled all forms of community wiki automatic conversions, not just for answers but for questions as well. ... To handle the cases spoken about* ***the abuse cases the system was originally meant to prevent***, *flags are now raised for moderator attention in the event of several edits."*

Comment: @BSMP unfortunately I can't right now since I only have 101 rep (from association bonus) and it won't let me put an answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention: this is a clear and exceptional abuse of the system.

Comment: Isn't it [automatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947)? Or did that change? Is the devil in the details?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The functionality described by Grace Note still exists, but didn't trigger in this case. The threshold is apparently set too high. Which makes sense... The absolute number of edits here is not the problem, but rather that each one is putting it into the review queue.